# How to generate the number of imageviews dynamically and how to set them to imageview in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. I have to display a text and along with that images. I am getting text and images from database. The database table contains
two columns.

Column1            Column2
text data          img1.png,img2.png,img3.png

text data2        img1.png

### text data3        img1.png,img2.png

### ----

---

Now i am getting the Column1 data in one str1 and column2 data in another str2.
I stored the str2 data in str3 array by spltting str2 with commas.

i.e str3 = str2.split(","); 
So str3 contains all the image names.

Now my requirement is based on the size of the str3 I need to generate those many imageviews.
For example str3 size is 2 so i have to set two image views dynamically and need to set the image. How can I do that?

Please help me with this task...
Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply need to search for "Android programmatically add view to layout."

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be something like this, I have not written code for any layout-parameters that you will need to do to format your layout according your designs.

This is to demonstarte how you can generate and add views to your activity programmatically.

```
        LinearLayout llMain = new LinearLayout(this);
        for(int i=0;i<totalRowSize;i++)
        {
            LinearLayout llRow = new LinearLayout(this);
            String imagesString = "";//assign database second column ;
            String[] arrImages = imagesString.split(",");
            for(int j=0;j<arrImages.length;j++)
            {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrImages[j]));// get bitmap from image path
                llRow.addView(iv);
            }
            llMain.addView(llRow);
        }
        setContentView(llMain);
```